# Could not stop click function on table td

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is after click on <-td-> it perform some action and after that user cant click that <-td-> again . so i can stop the same function to perform again. but even after that i unable to stop click function of particular <-td->.

```
$(".ticktack tr td").click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();

   // some other code below 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want to remove the click handler after first click happens.

```
$(".ticktack tr td").click(function(){
    // do something for first time
    alert("test");

    // unbind the click handler for only this td
    $(this).unbind('click');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you have to add class on `<td>` tag like `<td  class='on-click'>` now you have to follow below code

```
$(".ticktack tr td.on-click").click(function(e){
    $(this).removeClass("on-click");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with an if statement and remove its class when its clicked once

```
   if($(".ticktack tr td").click){
alert("test");
$(".ticktack tr td").removeClass(".active")
}
```